# jQuery UI autocomplete ajax with multiple values

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've checked several solutions like this:

[jQuery UI Autocomplete Multiple Values in Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199182/jquery-ui-autocomplete-multiple-values-in-textbox)
[jQuery UI Autocomplete Multiple Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675606/jquery-ui-autocomplete-multiple-values)

with no success.  I have a jQuery UI autocomplete working very well with the exception of search phrases with spaces in them.  For instance, I'll search "real" and get a list of results but if I enter "real estate" it bombs out after "real ".

Here's my current working code up to adding a space in the textbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
$(document).ready(function () {           
     /* auto complete for the menu search option */
    $("#txtSearchProgram").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/SpecialPages/Program-Autocomplete.aspx',
                data: { 'searchtext' : encodeURIComponent(request.term), 'langspecific' : '1' },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(jsonData) {
                    response(jsonData);
                }
            });
        },
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 2,
        open: function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("widget")
                   .appendTo("#autocomplete-results")
                   .css("position", "static")},
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).attr("placeholder", ui.item.label);
          return false;  
        }, 
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = ui.item.value;
            if (url != '#') {
                location.href = url;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is some code I tried from above links but continue to receive the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined" error

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function () {
     /* auto complete for the menu search option */
    $("#txtSearchProgram").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/SpecialPages/Program-Autocomplete.aspx',
                data: { 'searchtext' : encodeURIComponent(request.term) },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(jsonData) {
                    var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term); // errors out here
                    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
                    response($.grep(jsonData, function(item){return matcher.test(item.value);}) );
                }
            });
        },
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 2,
        open: function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("widget")
                   .appendTo("#autocomplete-results")
                   .css("position", "static")},
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).attr("placeholder", ui.item.label);
          return false;  
        }, 
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = ui.item.value;
            if (url != '#') {
                location.href = url;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I debug it I'm not getting much detail (not a strong front end dev) other than the error I already mentioned.

Comment: I think [you should try this way](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/05/jquery-ui-autocomplete-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-element-of-undefined/) by using .php style

Comment: Not sure @hmd using ".php style" will help anything.  As I stated first block of code works except for searching anything with a space in it.

Comment: So, did you compare the request headers and response of 'with space' and 'without space'? it should be same in your ajax request that you can find at browser's Developers Tool.

Comment: I did not.  I often forget those things doing all the backend programming.  I'll see if I can't compare and follow up.

Comment: How does the request and response data look like (in Firebug or Fiddler)? Is it OK, or at which point is the data different than what you would expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further testing I found the issue was with where I placed and encoded my parameters.  The code below is what I started with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
$(document).ready(function () {           
     /* auto complete for the menu search option */
    $("#txtSearchProgram").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/SpecialPages/Program-Autocomplete.aspx',
                data: { 'searchtext' : encodeURIComponent(request.term), 'langspecific' : '1' }, // problem here
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(jsonData) {
                    response(jsonData);
                }
            });
        },
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 2,
        open: function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("widget")
                   .appendTo("#autocomplete-results")
                   .css("position", "static")},
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).attr("placeholder", ui.item.label);
          return false;  
        }, 
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = ui.item.value;
            if (url != '#') {
                location.href = url;
            }
        }
    });
});  

</script>
```

And this is what I ended up with.  Note I removed the `data` attribute and simply created a query string.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">        
$(document).ready(function () {           
     /* auto complete for the menu search option */
    $("#txtSearchProgram").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/SpecialPages/Program-Autocomplete.aspx?searchtext=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + '&langspecific=1', // resolved
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(jsonData) {
                    response(jsonData);
                }
            });
        },
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 2,
        open: function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("widget")
                   .appendTo("#autocomplete-results")
                   .css("position", "static")},
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).attr("placeholder", ui.item.label);
          return false;  
        }, 
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = ui.item.value;
            if (url != '#') {
                location.href = url;
            }
        }
    });
});  

</script>
```